# Laravel4 how to apply *after* filters with Route::when()?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I want to apply a filter *after* any route with a given pattern. I can

```
Route::when('user/*', 'some-filter', array('get'));
```

but that will happen before the request is processed. I need to apply it after, like i am able to do with, for example, with

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'acl', 'after' => 'some-filter'), function() {})
```

Is there any Route::when() additional argument to obtain this?

Answer (score 0):

You could write the filter in the App::after() function in filters.php instead of using Route::when().

```
App::after(function($request, $response){
    // route filter here
});
```

To answer your question, I do not believe there is additional arguments to pass. The second parameter is expected to be a string so you won't be able to put **array('after' => 'some-filter')**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a filter after every route (request) you can use [Application events](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/lifecycle#application-events).

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    // Do stuff
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my need is not on every route. See edit pls

Comment: Then why not just enclose your /user routes inside the Route::group in your example?

Comment: Well i could, but i don't actually need to group any route, i just need that my filter applies on user/* after processing. That could be a valid workaround though